# Rails 4 - Nested Form (many to many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have the following schema:

```
attribute
----------
id
name

profile
----------
user_id
attribute_id
value

user
----------
id
name
```

What I am trying to do is display all the attributes and then for any attribute that the user does have in the profile it fills it in and an update can be performed. My background isn't ruby but I'm testing this framework for a proof of concept before possibly migrating an app.

I have mapped the association like that on the guides on rubyonrails.org (the appointments example)

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :profiles
    has_many :users, through: :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attribute
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :profiles
    has_many :attributes, through: :profiles

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles
end
```

I took the approach of using nested forms but unable to pass the model through even though the accepts_nested_attributes_for has been set.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
     <% Attribute.all.each do |attribute| %>
            <div>
                <%= attribute.name %>
            </div>
            <div>
                <%= f.fields_for :profiles do |upp| %>
                    <%= upp.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
                    <%= upp.hidden_field :attribute_id, :value => @attribute.id %>
                    <%= upp.text_field :value %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
    <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

e.g

```
Attributes
A
B
C
```

User has attribute A

```
A ["hello world"]
B [             ]
C [             ]
```

Attributes are dynamic, so if 2 new attributes are added, D and E would be shown as well

```
A ["hello world"]
B [             ]
C [             ]
D [             ]
E [             ]
```

How can I setup this form correctly so that it can be passed through as a model for saving? I assume the json would be something like

```
profile_attributes { [user_id:1 attribute_id:1 value:'hello world'], [user_id:1 attribute_id:2 value:''] }
```

I know the above form setup is not quite right but that is just one of several attempts I tried to see what it renders.

I tried:

```
<%= f.fields_for @user.profiles do |pp| %>
<% end %>
```

I even tried manually setting the field as arrays (similiar to asp.net mvc):

```
id=user[profiles][user_id]
id=user[profiles][attribute_id]
```

Controllers (they're empty shells at the moment, I just wanted to see the json output in the console)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end

class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(profiles_attributes: [:user_id, :attribute_id, :value])
        end
  end
end
```

I've tried many different approaches but with no success. Sometimes the form shows duplicated fields with same values, sometimes the form is shown but value is blank and upon submission complains about unpermitted parameter yet it was set in the controller.

Of course all the above can be done using javascript but I wanted to see if it was possible just using the model approach and nesting it.

Comment: Could you show your users_controller code.

Comment: I added them but they're basically empty and not implemented. I am just testing the output upon submission. The ProfileController is where I display these attributes and not on the User creation/edit page.

Comment: You are using <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> when you submit this, this will look for users update action in users_controller but it is empty, firstly set up your users_controller

Comment: When you mentioned this comment, I had a think about what was going on  so I adjusted my UserController and moved everything to user and it worked the way I had wanted. The answer below is not really the accepted answer. However is there anyway to do have a profile route in user which also acts as an update? From what I have seen the only way I could possibly do this is to have edit?form=profile and have templates in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

move form to your **users/edit.html.erb** and modify your users_controller as below

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    @user.profiles.build
  end


  def update
     if @user.update(user_params)
       #redirect user where you want
     end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      #permit user attributes along with profile attributes
    end

 end
```

Comment: I don't want it in the user controller but instead in the profile controller. I just want to update their attributes and none of their user details. Can the user be wrapped in the ProfileController instead? I've set the route to be get       'profile/:id'        =>  'profile#edit'

Comment: You can do this by your profile controller just define url in your 'form_for' that should be a url for your update action of profiles_controller and also you need to save(update) user to save your profiles.